# Convert nested json in rational data in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have data saved in a database, Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

What I need to do is to download specific data - query written and is working - to analyze these data. One of the columns is in json format, with following structure

```
{"name":{"meta_id","actualValues":{"item1":{"name":name,"value":value},
    "item_2":{"name":name,"value":value_2},
    "item_3":{"name":name,"value":value_3},
    "item_n":{"name":name,"value":value_n},},

    "setValues:{"item1":{"name":name,"value":value},
    "item_2":{"name":name,"value":value_2},
    "item_3":{"name":name,"value":value_3},
    "item_n":{"name":name,"value":value_n},}
}
```

The nested json file includes several hundreds of parameter and corresponding values

I managed to connect my database with python and control the query inside python. But if I want to analyze my data I need to convert the structure from the nested json to relational data. Doing this in python takes a very long time for few thousand rows. So I tried to convert the json inside the Database.
The expected output shall look like this

[image]

The blue columns shall represent "actualValues" and the yellow columns the "setValues". The **name_X** shall represent the name for **item_x**
I found the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) which gives some help about **json_value** and **json_query**.

However this functions only work in SQL Server higher than 2016. Unfortunately I just have the 2014 version.

Is there any way to convert a nested json into relational data, i.e. into a nice table, without a time consuming process?

For any kind of help I would be thankful

Comment: When you say relational data, do you mean a dataframe? like a spreadsheet etc?

Comment: yes :), exactly

Comment: so is this example one row with many columns or multiple rows? can you provide the expected output?

Comment: thanks for feedback: I updated my question

Cheers

Comment: It's probably best to not have two columns of the same name. Plus you just care about value? what happens to the name part of your items?

Comment: oh you are right. I did a mistake. What I want is a column with name as header and value as value

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood the question. But ultimately if you can only do it with a higher version you may have to do just that. In any case, you will have to do some processing in python if you want it as a dataframe

Comment: Ye. I did the pre-processing which takes much time. I tried to solve the issue for sql version 2014 by myself but I cannot manage that and need to upgrade to 2016.
Thanks anyway. At least I know now that I am not that stupid :)